# RBF Neural Networks C#

Tags: c#, neural-network

I'm trying to find a code for a neural networks with the Gaussian function as Radial basis function. I want to use the BackPropagation Learning Rule.

I have all the datas so all i need is the RBF neural network. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Encog library (C# and Java) has this functionality:

http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog